# fallo la activación de la conexión de red - VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, redes, configuración, virtualbox, conexión

les comento hace unas semanas instale virtualbox para realizar unas practicas que me piden en la universidad e instale una maquina virtual Ubuntu 18.04, mi problema consiste que cuando quiero utilizar adaptador puente como configuración de red como aparece en la siguiente imagen:

[image: mensaje de error que me sale]

cuando inicio la maquina, me aparece el símbolo de conectando a la red y luego de unos segundos me sale una notificación emergente diciendo: fallo la activación de la conexión de red, como se puede apreciar en la siguiente imagen:

[image: mensaje de error que me sale]

La verdad no tengo idea de que pueda ser, no utilizo nat porque necesito pinguear y comunicar ambas computadoras.

Tengo una Lenovo ideapad-330S, esta no cuenta con entrada para cable ethernet

siguiendo la recomendación Alexci, configurando el archivo de netplan para forzar que me de una dirección ip propia:

[image: mensaje de error que me sale]

cuando ingreso **ip a** al parecer aún sigue sin asignármela, además cuando intento hacer ping a mi maquina anfitrión me dice red no accesible.

[image: mensaje de error que me sale]

Comment: Para que funcione como puente necesitas otro adaptador (físico) de red.

Comment: @Sal Gracias por tu ayuda, pero y si quiero comunicar mi maquina host con la virtual cual seria otra forma de hacerlo? eh leido que NAT + Port forwarding es otra de hacerlo pero no si es factible a la hora de realizar practicas con netplan o webmin

Comment: Suena que con *Sólo-anfitrión* (*Host-only*) es suficiente. Con NAT y reenvío de puertos funcionará webmin pero no podrás hacer ping desde el anfitrión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Utilizando **adaptador puente** y **Nat(opcional)**.
Red Nat te da salida a internet para que puedas navegar mientras que el adaptador puente actua de [DHCP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_configuraci%C3%B3n_din%C3%A1mica_de_host) y te da un IP no utilizada por otra maquina de tu red para poder tener comunicación con otras maquinas de tu misma red.

He leido que no tienes la red Nat activa, es por eso mismo que te salta ese mensaje, de todas formas, no es necesario que tengas Nat activada para comunicarte.

**SI EL ADAPTADOR PUENTE NO TE ASIGNA IP :**
Tienes que modificar el archivo localizado en **/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml** de la siguiente manera : ***(NO UTILICES TABULACIONES)***
[image: Activar DHCP maquina virtual]
Después de esto, guarda los cambios y ejecuta un **netplan apply**
Ejecuta un **ip a** para comprobar que se ha asignado la ip.

Con la ip asginada prueba de hacer ping desde tu anfitrion a la maquina virtual y viceversa.
[image: Captura de ping anfitrion a maquina virtual]

**2.** Utilizando **red Nat** y **Nat(opcional)**.
Al abrir VirtualBox dirigte a "Archivo">"Preferencias">"Red" y modifica o bien agrega una conexion de red. Aqui lo que tienes que hacer es añadir la red en la que te quieres comunicar y establecer la mascara adecuada.

Una vez has modificado la red Nat, en tu maquina añades el adaptador de red "redNat". Seguido de esto, establece el nombre de la redNat modificada que utilizaras. (Tambien es recomendable que si tenias otra red anterior a esta reinices la MAC).

Te dejo una cuantas imagenes del proceso de la creación de dos redes Nat para que entiendas mejor el proceso.

[image: Preferencias]
Red1 para comunicarse con maquinas dentro de 192.168.2.X (mascara 24)

 
[image: Red1]
[image: Añadir red1 a la maquina]
Red2 para comunicarse con maquinas dentro de 64.34.29.X (mascara 28)
[image: Red2]
[image: Añadir red2 a la maquina]

Comment: En efecto, quiero hacer ping de mi maquina virtual a mi maquina anfitrión, pero utilizando la configuración adaptador puente.

Al principio la configuración predeterminada es NAT, esta configuración me fluye bien, pero el único detalle es que no se puede hacer ping a mi maquina anfitrión, así que la practica que estamos realizando en la universidad es haciéndolo por adaptador puente, es aquí donde llega mi problema ya que cuando utilizo esta configuración mi maquina no conecta a la red. 

no se si tenga algo que ver que mi computadora no cuenta con entrada física para el cable ethernet.

Comment: De acuerdo, entonces no la configuración de adaptador puente no te actua como DHCP y no te devuelve una IP verdad? Ahora te doy una respuesta.

Comment: Ya tienes la respuesta actualizada! Lo que probado con mi propia maquina para asegurarme que te funcionara. Si en vez de tener el archivo 01-network-manager-all.yaml tienes el archivo 50-cloud-init.yaml escribeme un comentario. Espero que te sirva

Comment: Ya he intentado como me haz dicho, pero al parecer sigue sin asignarme la **ip**, actualice mi pregunta para que puedas ver como tengo mi configuración, agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: Has ejecutado `netplan apply` después de introducir la configuración??

Comment: Efectivamente, así lo eh hecho, pero no me asigno ninguna **ip**

Comment: Qué extraño.... Lo último que puedo sugerirte que hagas es que instales otra máquina virtual y modifiques de nuevo el archivo. Fue lo que yo hice antes de escribirte la respuesta y no tuve ningún problema

Comment: Intente con Red NAT, y efectivamente pude conectar otra maquina virtual con ip's diferentes, pero aún no logro con la de anfitrión, pero por suerte puedo realizar las practicas sin la maquina anfitrión.

Comment: Me alegro que asi sea. De todas formas, si has configurado tu red Nat asi : `192.168.1.0/24` deberías poder tener comunicación con tu anfitrion